# Problem with extension schema in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, schema, rcp

Eclipse doesn't find the schema for an extension. However, the schemas for other extensions can be found.

Is there any best practice how to find the missing schema for an arbitrary extension?

Comment: "Eclipse doesn't find .." Are you getting specific errors?

Comment: Yes, the error message is: "No schema found for the xxxx extension point." I know it's a common bug, but those solutions i have found on the internet didn't work for me.